# Update first value in each list element in R

Tags: r, list

I would like to replace the first value in each list element with the second value from the same element.

For example I would like a function to transform lst into lst2

```
lst<-list(c(0:4),c(5:9))
lst

lst2<-list(c(1, c(1:4)),c(6,c(6:9)))
lst2
```

I know that I can do

```
lst[[1]][1]=lst[[1]][2]
lst[[2]][1]=lst[[2]][2]
```

But I would like a function to iterate over all list elements. I have tried various things (all unsuccessful) with lapply such as:

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[1]=x[2])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and we need to return the `x` if we are using anonymous function call.

```
lstN <- lapply(lst, function(x) {x[1] <- x[2]
                         x})
identical(lst2, lstN)
#[1] TRUE
```